# Не обрабатываются клики selenium IDE по dhtmlxtoolbar кнопкам

Tags: selenium

Здравствуйте. В приложении используется данный тулбар
http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxToolbar/

Не обрабатывается команда click по кнопке тулбара в Selenium IDE 2.8.0.
Пробовал и clickAt и mouseDown - не работает.

В демо версии по ссылке можете сами попробовать. Собственно вопрос: как сделать чтобы оно работало по команде click? Почему не работает сразу?

Answer (score 2):

Нашел ответ на форуме dhtmlx

> http://forum.dhtmlx.com/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=23134&p=74389&hilit=selenium#p74389
>
> onclick is not the only event that should be triggered to click an
>   item. There is also on mouseover, mousedown, mouseup, mouseout. The
>   order of event clicks can be like so: mouseover, mousedown, click,
>   mouseup, mouseout. Possibly this will help.

То есть чтобы полностью вызвать событие нажатия ЛКМ нужно вызвать последовательно события `mouseover`, `mousedown`, `click`, `mouseup`, `mouseout`.

В моем случае на элементе тулбара twoStateButton вместо `click` работает с событием `mouseDown`, а вот на элементе button работает если последовательно вызвать `mouseover`, `mousedown`, `click`.